# Add extension to certificate using CryptoApi

Tags: c++, c, winapi, x509certificate, cryptoapi

I'm trying to add an extension to the certificate request using the CryptoApi. Here is the code that I use:

```c
char extensionValue[] = "testValue";


_CRYPTOAPI_BLOB myBlob = {
    (DWORD)strlen(extensionValue),
    (BYTE*)extensionValue
};

wchar_t pszString[1000];
DWORD dwLength = 1000;
bool checkEncodingToBase64Test = CryptBinaryToStringW(myBlob.pbData, myBlob.cbData, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, (LPWSTR)pszString, &dwLength);


BSTR bstrValue = pszString;
BSTR bstrName = SysAllocString(L"1.2.643.100.111");

HRESULT checkAddingExtention = pEnroll->addExtensionToRequest(0, bstrName, bstrValue);
```

To check the request I use https://certlogik.com/decoder/
When checking here get this result:

```
Requested Extensions:
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
            TLS Web Client Authentication, E-mail Protection, 1.2.643.2.2.34.6
        X509v3 Key Usage: 
            Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
        1.2.643.100.111: 
            testValue

SEQUENCE {:
   OBJECT IDENTIFIER '1 2 643 100 111'
   OCTET STRING 74 65 73 74 56 61 6C 75 65
}
```

But I need to get this type of structure:

```
SEQUENCE {
  OBJECT IDENTIFIER '1 2 643 100 111'
  OCTET STRING, encapsulates {
  UTF8String
  'testValue'
  }
}
```

How to achieve this? How to put a UTF8-string in extension?

Comment: Answer was founded. Need to use CryptEncodeObjectEx from CryptoApi with X509_ANY_STRING parameter to encode  CERT_NAME_VALUE structure. Then encode to Base64 using CryptBinaryToString

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way

```
WCHAR *id = L"testValue";
CERT_NAME_VALUE otherNameValue = { CERT_RDN_UTF8_STRING, (DWORD)wcslen(id) * sizeof(wchar_t), (PBYTE)id };

BYTE *buf;
DWORD size = 0;
CryptEncodeObjectEx(PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING, X509_ANY_STRING, &otherNameValue, CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG, NULL, &buf, &size);

CERT_EXTENSION CertExtension[] = { {"1.2.643.100.111", FALSE, size, buf} };

...
LocalFree(buf);
```